# Why do some people return after they throw Exceptions?

Tags: php, exception

I see in some of the code on Github

```
if($something_funky_happens){
  throw new \LogicException(...);
  return;
}
```

Is this required, or it is not important to return?
because I know that after you throw exceptions the script stops, so further code does not run

Comment: statement is not reachable, perhaps introduced later?

Comment: no, the return is in the same IF statement. see here for an example: https://github.com/fabpot/Sami/blob/master/Sami/Parser/DocBlockParser.php#L90

Comment: Why do some people return after throwing anything?  Shouldn't they know better?  Great question, though.

Comment: @Alex Seems it is fixed here :) https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sami/commit/8f9bc5e184fc7deb3c0c505b480c5e1476c92d97

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## unreachable code

I tend to denote it an error in their code. The statement is not reachable. Every static code anaylsis tool will complain about this unreachable statement. Even when it has no harm in this case you will get a load of warnings when checking your code. If you turn these warning type off you will perhaps miss other logic errors within your code. It's a real bad smell and it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Because they made a mistake, or it's their personal preference. It's impossible to get to the `return` in that code, but there's no real harm in including it.

From [the docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) *<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>*:

> When an exception is thrown, **code following the statement will not be executed**, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block.

Comment: No "harm", but if you use an intelligent IDE it will probably complain about unreachable code. I would advice not to write code like this. Jetbrains for example flags this with the hint "unreachable statement".

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is just for better readability....so you can scan the code faster for exit points, if you pretend that every exit point is seperated by a new line.

Comment: How does it improve readabiltiy if you stop reading the code and wonder why there is an additional return?

Comment: The author might pretend that everybody is following this weird convention. I don't know what it is for, but I don't think it is an error, since it is in the code of the symfony creator and since so many people are following his repos on github someone would have reported it.

Comment: Ok, you now got me to download the current Symfony ... out of curiosity. Last time I looked at it the code didn't look like it was created by clean code fetishists. You deny that it could be an "error" because the code was found in the project of the Symfony grandmaster? Your argument seems invalid. I don't know him, don't want to say that he is no smart guy. But Symfony is full of smells. PHPDOCs not matching method signatures, some unused local variables, some unused method parameters ... just saying.

Comment: I don't like Symfony either...but I'm sure they have a reason for that in their point of view.

Answer (score 4):

I find this convention useful, as when trying to read existing code, an **early exit** can break expectations of the code flow. and often deserves to be signposted. It's almost a goto.

I read from outermost blocks to innermost, not sequentially, so anything buried inside a block looks less important at first glance.

Comparing:

```
function doStuff {
  if (Y) {
    ##
    ## Stuff happens
    ##
  }
  else {
    ##
    ## Other Stuff happens
    ##
  }
  ##
  ## So I assume this always happens
  ##
}
```

with

```
function doStuff {
  if (Y) {
    ##
    ## Stuff happens
    ##
  }
  else {
    ##
    ## Other Stuff happens
    return; 
    # ^- this is easy to spot when scanning
    ##
  }
  ##
  ## This *usually* happens
  ##
}
```

I prefer the latter, *even if it can be a little redundant*.

I do accept that that's mostly because I'm 100x more conditioned to seeing 'return' as an important keyword, vs the number of times I have to expect exceptions, but I can spot a stand-alone 'return;' (or 'break;', or even 'continue;') *much faster* in screenfuls of code than I can pick out "throw new Exception(xxx,yyy);" at a distance when scrolling fast.

If I worked on code where exception-handling was a *much* more frequent method of process-flow-management, I may become more sensitized to spotting 'throw' as a keyword, but I'm not.

But then, I'm also guilty of redundant signposting like:

```
function doStuff() {
  if (X) {
    ## Do this
  }
  else {
    ## Do that
  }
  /* Should not get here. */
  return NULL;
}
```

... but only in extreme cases where the above logic is hard to follow, *such as when there were early exits expected.*