# Why return void if the return statement is never reached?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, return

This is a bit of a different question because it is not directly related to my code but to code that causes a problem in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317520/laravel-using-throttle-in-a-custom-login-controller).

When digging through the code related to this other question, I found a weird `return` statement that I don't understand. Before going on with my question, please have a look at these two code snippets from the `laravel/framework` code.

**Trait [\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php):**

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

**Trait [\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php):**

```
/**
 * Redirect the user after determining they are locked out.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
{
    $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(
        $this->throttleKey($request)
    );
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [Lang::get('auth.throttle', ['seconds' => $seconds])],
    ])->status(429);
}
```

In the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, it is checked if there have been made too many authentication attempts for a given user. If so, an event is fired and a lockout response is returned. So far so good.

What I don't understand is the `return` statement in front of `$this->sendLockoutResponse($request)`. Given method does always throw an exception and does return nothing (well, it would return `void`, but it doesn't, because it always `throws`).

**So what is the purpose of the `return` statement here?** Is it as hint for the reader that the `login()` is cancelled at this point or is this some special syntax I never heard of before?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I'd think it's to prevent the need of changing `login()` code if something in `sendLockoutResponse()` changes. This enables you to rewrite `sendLockoutResponse()` and return a response instead.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a definitive answer or if it's just @taylorotwell giving us something to think about. But I like your idea about maintainability!

Comment: Similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547656/why-do-some-people-return-after-they-throw-exceptions)

Comment: I think that one is slightly different because the `return` is placed in the same method. Here the explanation of @devk would not work.